# Laravel Inertia, CORS with google login

Tags: laravel, vue.js

am using ziggy with laravel and inertia, now using google login, i get the following error:
`has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
here is my laravel routes:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')
    ->name('login.provider');

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback')
    ->name('login.callback');
```

how would i solve it please?

Comment: You are trying to send request from different domain. Learn what CORS is and how to "fix" it.

Comment: A link to get you started https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

The response from the google service is missing the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` so the browser is blocking it.

Try to research a way to have that header included in the response.